# Create haskell IO wrapper

Tags: haskell, io-monad

In the GHC manual section on FFI, it is stated that the programmer can use `newtype` to create a wrapper monad around the IO monad and use it in place of the IO monad when calling foreign code. ([GHC manual](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/ffi-chap.html#newtype-wrapping-of-the-io-monad))

So far, I have:

```
newtype PGm a = PGm (IO a)
instance Monad PGm where
   (>>=) a b = ...
   (>>)  a b = ...
   return a  = PGm (return a) --I think
   fail a    = PGm (fail a)   --I think
```

I'm at a loss regarding how to implement `(>>=)` and `(>>)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just unwrap and rewrap each operation. The hard part is figuring out where the unwrapping and rewrapping goes:

```
newtype PGm a = PGm (IO a)
instance Monad PGm where
   (>>=) (PGm a) b = PGm (a >>= (unPGm . b))
     where
       unPGm (PGm x) = x
   (>>)  (PGm a) (PGm b) = a >> b
   return a  = PGm (return a)
   fail a    = PGm (fail a)
```

However, this won't quite be enough, as Haskell requires instances for `Functor` and `Applicative` before a `Monad` instance may be defined. An easier solution would be to put the `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` at the top of your file (or enable `:set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` in GHCi), which lets you do this;

```
newtype PGm a = PGm (IO a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

The idea is that if you enable this extension, GHC will be smart enough to automatically derive newtype instances from their 'base' ones.

Comment: Also, `>>=` is simpler if you put `unPGm` in the definition of `PGm` using record syntax: `newtype PGm a = PGm { unPGm :: IO a }`

Comment: @chepner Yes it definitely is, but I decided to keep EdBehn's definition for now. I would definitely define this sort of type using record syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I had figured out some of that after I posted, but your way of implementing >>= is much cleaner than mine. Of course using deriving is cleaner still.

Comment: @EdBehn You're welcome! For this sort of thing I almost always use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` unless I need something special. There's [plenty other useful extensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extensions-to-the-deriving-mechanism) as well - I would highly recommend having a look through them!